# Use of scope in rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was reading Rails routes guide and came to this part:

If you want to route /posts (without the prefix /admin) to Admin::PostsController, you could use:

```
scope module: 'admin' do
  resources :posts, :comments
end
```

Ok I understood this part, it says if we use scope the way it shows us, instead of for example `/admin/posts`  we can directly say `/posts`

But I didn't underatand the second part below: What does this one do?

If you want to route /admin/posts to PostsController (without the Admin:: module prefix), you could use:

```
scope '/admin' do
  resources :posts, :comments
end
```

Comment: what exactly you are not able to understand?

Comment: what is problem? I see that you are understand. scope 'admin' give us an url.

Comment: @JakubKuchar : I didn't understand the second one that uses URL in the scope, what is the difference between that one and the first one that used module in the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

1. Use if you want to have controller in namespace ONLY, but don't want namespaced url for this controller
2. Use if you want namespaced url ONLY but not controller